# Java execute file relative to jar

Tags: java, file, io, runtime

I have a c# console application I will be sending commends to using Java, with the techniques described here [Sending commands to a console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013721/sending-commands-to-a-console-application)

My issue is that the console application is in a folder that's in the same folder with the jar, and I can't find out how to execute a file relative to the same directory as the jar.

I tried a lot of things in Java, like

```
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runtime_libraries/consoleapp.exe");
```

But it says the file can't be found.

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I assumed it would be simple, but apparently it's not.

So my question is, how can I put a relative path into the Runtime exec?

Comment: @paisanco I have a C# console application which I am trying to execute from Java

Comment: @paisanco Yeah, I re-worded it a bit

Comment: yeah, you need to somehow find the path of the jar file :)  maybe from `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`. It's also possible from Class/ClassLoader.

Comment: @bayou.io Thats kinda close, but it returns the paths to all the libraries on the classpath

Comment: yes, and you need to parse and extract just that jar...

Comment: @bayou.io Will it always return it with the path to the jar as the first path, or it there a possibility the order could be different sometimes?

Comment: don't depend on the order.

Comment: @bayou.io How am I suppose to know which is the right path then if I can't depend on the order?

Comment: by matching the name of the jar?

Comment: Oh yeah, shouldn't be doing this so late at night xD

Comment: 1.  Verify your current running location using `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` and make sure it's where you expect it to be; 2. Verify the existence of the `consoleapp.exe` using `System.out.println(new File("runtime_libraries/consoleapp.exe").exists()));`

Comment: I just found `System.getProperty("user.dir")` and it points to the correct directory for me.

Comment: @MadProgrammer If you want to make that an answer, I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever you're faced with this kind of issue, you need to do some preliminary checks...

1. Verify your current running location using `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` and make sure it's where you expect it to be;
2. Verify the existence of the `consoleapp.exe` using `System.out.println(new File("runtime_libraries/consoleapp.exe").exists()));`

Most IDEs allow you to change the working directory during development.  When in production, you should ensure that the working directory is set correctly (for example, under Windows, you can configure the short-cuts to "start" in a specified location)